# Debugging Military Tools for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, arcgis-military-analyst

I am looking to make some updates to the [Distance and Direction AddIn for ArcGIS](https://github.com/Esri/distance-direction-addin-dotnet/tree/dev/source/addins).

I have downloaded the source code and opened the solution. However, I cannot seem to get the project to output any info to the debug window. I added some break points and when I run the solution it stops on the breakpoints but the `Debug.Print` statements do nothing. I am in Debug config in the solution.

How can I debug this solution?

Comment: There's a bunch of questions (with some answers) on debugging add-ins. Maybe search here to see if any of them are useful. (I used "debug" add-in")

Comment: After days of trial and error it appears that the addin script has changed if you are using VS2015. That was difficult to track but that seems to have fixed my issue. Also the code bombs if I leave the form displayed and then run the debugger again. I have to close it down before I close arcmap.

Comment: Did you try using Debug>Attach to Process... instead of starting arcmap from VS?

Comment: What I found was that the line with addin dll in the script has to be modified if using VS2015. Also the addin form has to be closed after every test run otherwise an exception will occur when it tries to initialize. Took me many hours to figure this out. Wish there was some notes on this.